# Add a value to each of the array element between two given indices successively

Tags: java, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I am trying to solve the [HackerRank: Array Manipulation](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem) problem using Java.

The problem that I am facing is that the program is running for half of the test cases, while for the other half it is showing "Execution couldn't be completed because of Timeout". It seems like there is a more efficient way to do the problem such that the program is executed within the given time frame. If anybody could guide me regarding the issue, it would be of great help.

**[Problem description](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem)**

> Starting with a 1-indexed array of zeros and a list of operations, for
>   each operation add a value to each of the array element between two
>   given indices, inclusive. Once all operations have been performed,
>   return the maximum value in your array.
>
> For example, the length of your array of zeros n=10. Your list of
>   queries is as follows:
>
> ```
> a b k
> 1 5 3
> 4 8 7
> 6 9 1
> ```
>
> Add the values of  between the indices  and  inclusive:
>
> ```
> index->    1 2 3  4  5 6 7 8 9 10
>           [0,0,0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0]
>           [3,3,3, 3, 3,0,0,0,0, 0]
>           [3,3,3,10,10,7,7,7,0, 0]
>           [3,3,3,10,10,8,8,8,1, 0]
> ```
>
> The largest value is 10 after all operations are performed.
>
> **Function Description**
>
> Complete the function arrayManipulation in the editor below. It must
>   return an integer, the maximum value in the resulting array.
>
> arrayManipulation has the following parameters:
>
> - n - the number of elements in your array
> - queries - a two dimensional array of queries where each queries[i] contains three integers, a, b, and k.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The first line contains two space-separated integers \$n\$ and \$m\$,
>   the size of the array and the number of operations.
>
> Each of the next \$m\$ lines contains three space-separated integers
>   \$a\$,\$b\$  and \$k\$, the left index, right index and summand.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> - \$ 3 \le n \le 10^7 \$
> - \$ 1 \le m \le 2 \cdot 10^5 \$
> - \$ 1 \le a \le b \le n \$
> - \$ 0 \le k \le 10^9 \$
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Return the integer maximum value in the finished array.

**My Solution:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    // Complete the arrayManipulation function below.
    static long arrayManipulation(int n, int[][] queries) {

        int queryLength = queries.length;

        System.out.println(queryLength);

        long[] p = new long[n];
        int a = 0 , b = 0 , k = 0;

        long max=0; 

        // initialize p

        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        {
            p[i] = 0 ;
        }

        for(int i = 0 ; i < queryLength ; i++ )
        {
            a = queries[i][0];
            b = queries[i][1];
            k = queries[i][2];

            for(int j = (a-1) ; j <= (b-1) ; j++)
            {
                p[j] = p[j] + k ;
            }

        }

        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        {
            if(p[i]>max)
            {
                max = p[i];
            }
        }

        return max;

    }

    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        String[] nm = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

        int n = Integer.parseInt(nm[0]);

        int m = Integer.parseInt(nm[1]);

        int[][] queries = new int[m][3];

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            String[] queriesRowItems = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
            scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                int queriesItem = Integer.parseInt(queriesRowItems[j]);
                queries[i][j] = queriesItem;
            }
        }

        long result = arrayManipulation(n, queries);

        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result));
        bufferedWriter.newLine();

        bufferedWriter.close();

        scanner.close();





    }
}
```

Comment: You need a better algorithm. You might want to look at other questions about the same challenge, such as https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/185320/35991, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/154144/35991, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/95755/35991. The languages are different, but the ideas apply here as well.

Comment: @MartinR Went through those questions. Not able to comprehend what they have mentioned as the language used for coding is different. If someone could guide what algorithmic changes should I make, maybe I can write the program on my own. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some general remarks:

> ```
> System.out.println(queryLength);
> ```

The function should only return the result, but not print anything.

> ```
> int a = 0 , b = 0 , k = 0;
> ```

The initial values are not used, and variables should be declared at the narrowest scope, in this case, inside the loop:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < queryLength ; i++ )
{
    int a = queries[i][0];
    int b = queries[i][1];
    int k = queries[i][2];
    // ...
}
```

Iterating over all queries can also be done with an “enhanced for loop”:

```
for (int[] query: queries)
{
    int a = query[0];
    int b = query[1];
    int k = query[2];
    // ...
}
```

Here

> ```
> for(int j = (a-1) ; j <= (b-1) ; j++)
> ```

the parentheses are not needed, and this

> ```
>  p[j] = p[j] + k ;
> ```

can be shortened to

```
p[j] += k ;
```

The initialization

> ```
> // initialize p
> for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
> {
>     p[i] = 0 ;
> }
> ```

is not needed because all elements are initialised to 0 by default.

It might be a matter of personal preference, but I would always put horizontal space around operators and keywords, e.g. in

> ```
> if(p[i]>max)
> ```

There are also some unneeded import statements, but those are given by the submission template.

---

But your real problem is that the algorithm is too slow. The inner loop runs up to \$ 10^{7} \$ times, for each of the up to \$ 2 \cdot 10^{5} \$ queries.

The main idea to improve the performance is to represent the data differently. Instead of storing and updating the array with the actual numbers, one can store and update an array which holds the *differences* between successive numbers.

Initially, all differences are zero.

Then for each query \$ (a, b, k) \$ you only have to update two entries in the differences array: One difference increases by \$ k\$, and one difference decreases by \$ k \$.

Finally you compute the actual numbers by accumulating the differences, and determine the maximum value.

This should be much faster, because the inner loop has been eliminated.

---

Let's take the given example with \$n = 10\$ and the queries

```
a b k
1 5 3
4 8 7
6 9 1
```

Instead of maintaining an array of the \$ n \$ numbers

```
index:             1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
initial array:    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
after (1, 5, 3):  [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
after (4, 8, 7):  [3, 3, 3,10,10, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0]
after (6, 9, 1):  [3, 3, 3,10,10, 8, 8, 8, 1, 0]
```

we maintain an array of \$ n+1 \$ differences, where each entry \$ d[i] \$  holds the difference \$a[i+1] - a[i] \$:

```
index:             0, 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
initial diffs:    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
after (1, 5, 3):  [3, 0, 0, 0, 0,-3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
after (4, 8, 7):  [3, 0, 0, 7, 0,-3, 0, 0,-7, 0, 0]
after (6, 9, 1):  [3, 0, 0, 7, 0,-2, 0, 0,-7,-1, 0]
final array:         [3, 3, 3,10,10, 8, 8, 8, 1, 0]
```

Do you see that only two entries are updated for each query? Can you figure out the pattern?

The final array is reconstructed by accumulating the final entries in the differences array.

Comment: And I don't want to deprive you from the satisfaction to implement that successfully, therefore I don't post the code for the new algorithm  :)

Comment: Thank you sir for your insights. But I didn't quite understand the difference portion. Sir, it would be of great help if you would elaborate this a little more.

Comment: @Soumee: I have added an example.

Comment: Thank you, Martin. I wrote the code and ran it. It runs perfectly fine. I couldn't have come up with the logic on my own. Now I have to figure out why this "shorthand" algorithm mathematically leads to the "mechanism" of this program. How can someone figure out the shorthand logic behind codes such as these?

Comment: @Soumee: I am afraid that “how can someone figure out ...” goes beyond the scope of a code review :) It is often in these challenges that one has to come up with a “suitable” representation of the data in  order to solve the problem in time, and there is no general mechanism how to do that. – In this particular case, if you wonder *why* it works: If `d[i] = a[i+1]-a[i]` is the list of differences, then `a[i] = d[0]+d[1]+...+d[i-1]`.

Comment: Alright. I get it :)